# "Cannot assign must be a instance" while assigning that specific instance

Tags: python, django

There are many related questions on SO about this topic, but they all seem to deal with cases where the element being assigned is actually the `instance.id` or a string with the instance name.

I have two models, one called `Photo`, the other called `Material`.

```
class Photo(models.Model):
     mat = models.ForeignKey(
        Material, related_name='photos',null=True, blank=True)
```

In the shell, I get a `Photo` object, and I create a `Material` object.

```
[in : 1]p = Photo.objects.all()[0] # get the first
[in : 2]m, bool = Material.objects.get_or_create(id=1) # get_or_create returns a tuple, take the first

[in : 3]p
[out:1] <Photo: Photo object>
[in : 4]m
[out:2] <Material:Material object>

[in : 5]p.mat = m

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-836d23304359> in <module>()
----> 1 p.mat = m

/home/rootadmin/opensurfaces/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.pyc in __set__(self, instance, value)
    595                     instance._meta.object_name,
    596                     self.field.name,
--> 597                     self.field.rel.to._meta.object_name,
    598                 )
    599             )

ValueError: Cannot assign "<Material: Material object>": "Photo.mat" must be a "Material" instance.
```

As far as I can tell, `m` is a `Material` instance. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check how Material model is imported to the file and make sure it is the same model which is the ForeignKey for Photo ? It looks like you have the wrong Material class imported.

Comment: Sorry my codeblock wasn't clear enough. I index with `[0]` on get or create, meaning it returns the actually object instead of the tuple. This can also been seen in input line 4.

Comment: didn't notice that. This is format we usually do. return to two variables.

Comment: Yea, I probably should have made it more explicit in the question that I index.

Comment: Can you check how Material model is imported to the file and make sure it is the same model which is the ForeignKey for Photo ?

Comment: Ha, found it, thanks to your. I had double checked the import locations, which were correct, but turns out the created `Material` instance was declared somewhere else, e.g. I had two difference `Material` classes, and I tried to assign the wrong one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This error raise usually when you trying to assign a instance.id instead of instance.
In the django, you are need to saaign a instance to all the ForeignKey fields.
Instance Ex:

**mat = Material.objects.all()[0]**

Comment: Usually, yes, but regretfully that's  not the case here. The `m` object is truly a `Material` instance.

Answer (score 0):

The element `m` is an actual `Material` instance. This doesn't mean it is the *right* `Material` instance.

In my case, it turned out there were two separate declarations of a class named `Material`. As a result,  I was trying to assign the wrong `Material` instance.